# Why is the width of my <td> block bigger than 50px. If I specifically tell it to be max-width and width = 50px

Tags: html, css, html-table, django-templates, email-client

This is my table:

```html
<table style="width: 84%; min-width: 330px; margin-left: 8%; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 8%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50px; border-top: solid 1px #dedede; background: yellow; max-width: 50px;">
                            <img style="width: 50px; background: red" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/co.psngr.gopublic.staging/media/product/1/fbb3f543c5c349b09b59bf19a1e6a6d9.png">
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="1" style="border-top: solid 1px #dedede; padding: 20px 10px; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;color: #333333; width: 50%;">
                            <b><span style="color: #24b646">3 x </span>Psngr Beacon</b><br/>
                            <span style="font-size: 14px; color: #899ba7;">Bluetooth 4 (BLE) USB iBeacon\u2122</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="
                          width: 100px;
                          text-align: right;
                          border-top: solid 1px #dedede;
                          padding: 20px 0px;
                          font-weight: bold; color: #24b646;
                          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                          font-size: 18px;
                          letter-spacing: 0.2px; word-wrap: break-word">
                            € 74.85
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

As you can see. the table has a picture that is 50px inside, colored with red. But then the  is twice as big as the picture, even thought the same width is set to both:

[image]

When i inspect, element style says 50px; But if I highlight it, it says 109x77

I am using this for django templates, so I cannot use @mediaQueries, or classes. I just wanted to let you guys know in advance regarding this

Comment: Thats how table cells work. Maybe don't use a table here? Also, have you tried setting `table-layout:fixed;` on your `<table>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by some styles on your other two `td` elements. Since you had `padding-top` and/or `padding-bottom` on the other two, then created extra vertical space that you don't want on the first one. Also, you originally had the width of the second `td` set to 50%: that pulled the first `td` to be wider than 50px.

I took those things out in the snippet below as a starting point - you can make adjustments to the other 2 `td` in different ways so that the first one doesn't have the undesired effects.

```html
<table style="width: 84%; min-width: 330px; margin-left: 8%; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 8%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50px; border-top: solid 1px #dedede; background: yellow; max-width: 50px;">
                        <img style="width: 50px; background: red" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/co.psngr.gopublic.staging/media/product/1/fbb3f543c5c349b09b59bf19a1e6a6d9.png">
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-top: solid 1px #dedede; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;color: #333333; padding: 0 40px">
                        <b><span style="color: #24b646">3 x </span>Psngr Beacon</b><br/>
                        <span style="font-size: 14px; color: #899ba7;">Bluetooth 4 (BLE) USB iBeacon\u2122</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="
                      text-align: right;
                      border-top: solid 1px #dedede;
                      font-weight: bold; color: #24b646;
                      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                      font-size: 18px;
                      letter-spacing: 0.2px; word-wrap: break-word">
                        € 74.85
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that happens because you set the middle td's width to 50%, so it'll change the first td's width to take up the remaining space of the table row. Setting the width of the second td to 100% should fix that.